# symfony2 catch SQLSTATE Unknown database if host is down

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I was just wandering how can we catch the error sent by Symfony when the database is down, due to a problem with the web host for exemple.

In exemple, it would allow me to redirect the user on a specific page if my database is not found .

Should i use `try{}catch{}` somwhere in the doctrine code to catch any error during the connection?

Answer (score 1):

You can create [event listener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html) for `kernel.exception` event which would get this exception and change the response for user.